# How can I find out how browsers encode URIs entered into the address bar

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, safari

The mdn docs for encodeUri and encodeUriComponent describe that single quotes are not encoded as they are valid in a url without encoding and this works across browsers the same way.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent

However browser address bars seem to have their own rules for encoding URI's. If you put a single quote into a URI in Chrome or Safari, it will encode it to %27, Firefox appears to do the same and then maybe pretty prints it again as the single quote character

i.e. before navigating to the url in chrome:
[image]

after hitting enter / navigating to the url
[image]

I can't seem to find any documentation about how browsers encode these in their address bars. I have only come across this with the single quote character but curious as to why this is different to the javascript implementation for encoding and why it is encoded at all when the spec says they are fine.

Answer (score 0):

I've wondered this, too, myself. What happens is the values are converted into hex data (like how ' turns into 27), then a % is added in front to distinguish the characters from the rest of the URL. When the data is displayed, in the case of FireFox, it turns back into the original form. [Here's a good website to see what I'm talking about.](https://hexed.it/)

*I think the reason browsers do this is to prevent XSS attacks, but I am not 100% sure.*

Comment: Right, I understand how they are converted, but all characters have an encoded value representation. My question is pretty specifically around why single quote is encoded when it isn't necessary.

What makes you think this is related to prevention of XSS attacks?

Comment: Because single quotes can be used to describe strings or anything related to the DOM.